# Too Many Redirect After Http to Https Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I have recently used let's encrypt SSL certificate to move my wordpress site from HTTP:// to HTTPS://. However, as soon as I update wordpres Site URL and Home URL from Wordpress Settings, the site stopped functioning with message `Too many redirects`

What I have Tried so far:

1) Exported SQL script, Find and Replaced `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` and again imported back the sql script.

2) Updated .htaccess with following code

```
#Begin SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
#END SSL
```

3) Also updated wp-config by adding following line at the begining

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');
```

However, non of these works.

`http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php` mentioning this site is moved permanently to and fro between `https://example.com/` to `http://example.com`

Please, suggest some idea.

Comment: If you open the F12 developer tools in your browser, go to the Network tab, and (in Chrome) check "Preserve Log," then open a page, what do you see?  My guess is an endless series of redirects but edit your question to include the results.

Comment: @dave Yeah there are endless redirection that is what I was trying to mention. It is redirecting between `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` infinitely